# Crear un array en PL/SQL de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, array

Estoy intentando crear un array en **MySQL** *como se realiza en Oracle* para un procedimiento (**procedure**), pero no logro conseguirlo. Con este código lo estoy intentando:

```
# .... Código .... #

DECLARE

   type array_letras IS VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR(1);
   letra array_letras;

BEGIN

   letra := array_letras('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');

# .... Código .... #
```

Comment: 1) MySQL no posee PL/SQL, 2) MySQL no posee el concepto de arreglo. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar una tabla temporal y/o cursores para resolver el problema.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza♦ Vaya, pues habra que tirar de tabla temporal, gracias.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ¿podrías añadir tu comentario como respuesta para que dddenis la pueda dar por buena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql no soporta arrays, sin embargo puedes hacer un arreglo parecido a Json separando los valores por un caracter.

```html
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `_prueba_sp_array`(
 IN `p_cadena` TEXT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
declare separador char(1);
declare tamano_separador int;
declare valor_ind varchar(11);
declare tamano_ind_x int;
declare cadena_restante varchar(255);
#establecemos separador
set separador = ',';
set tamano_separador = length(separador);

REPEAT
#evaluamos si cadena restante es nulo, es decir: para el primer valor se "isnull" y para los demas "else"
IF isnull(cadena_restante) THEN
 #extraemos el primer valor de la cadena proporcionada
 set valor_ind = substring_index(p_cadena, separador, 1);
 #contamos cuantos caracteres tiene el valor extraido (izq a derecha)
 set tamano_ind_x = length(valor_ind);
 #definimos la cadena que queda (saltandonos los valores que ya tomamos) es decir, el individual1 + separador +1.
 set cadena_restante = substring(p_cadena,(tamano_separador+tamano_ind_x+1),length(p_cadena));
ELSE
 #extraemos el primer valor de la cadena dada por parametro
 set valor_ind = substring_index(cadena_restante, separador, 1);
 #contamos cuantos caracteres tiene el valor extraido (izq a derecha)
 set tamano_ind_x = length(valor_ind);
 #definimos la cadena que queda (saltandonos los valores que ya tomamos) es decir, el individual1 + separador +1.
 set cadena_restante = substring(cadena_restante,(tamano_separador+tamano_ind_x+1),length(p_cadena));
END IF;
#aca debe ir codigo que actualiza los registros
#select/insert u cualquier operacion que desees operar con el arreglo;

until length(cadena_restante) = 0
END REPEAT;

END
```

Entonces desde tu programa ya solo debes llamar al procedimiento almacenado de esta forma:

```html
CALL `_prueba_sp_array`('id1,id2,id3,id4,id5')
```

El inconveniente seria que solo puedes pasar una "columna".

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo simple que te puede ayudar a simular un vector:

```
set mes=ELT(MONTH(CURDATE()),'ENERO','FEBRERO','MARZO','ABRIL','MAYO','JUNIO','JULIO','AGOSTO','SEPTIEMBRE','OCTUBRE','NOVIEMBRE','DICIEMBRE');
```