# ¿Es posible en SQL crear un "array" de varchar?

Tags: mysql, sql, random, innodb

Se que para un int esta el rand(), pero para un varchar creo (en lo que conozca) no existe algun tipo de rand.
Mi consulta es si es posible hacer algo similar a un array donde con un rand elija una casilla de ese "array" y aparezca en un INSERT INTO.

Algo así como

```
Nombres = ["Hernesto", "Carlos"];

INSERT INTO Persona (Nombre ) VALUES (Nombres["Numero Aleatorio"])
```

Todo esto con un SP llamado sp_NombreAleatorio

Comment: Estas trabajando en PHP,JS? o solo SQL?

Comment: Solo SQL, se que en php y js esta la posibilidad de hacerlo

Comment: Pero en que lenguaje estas trabajando para poder ayudarte.. o solo buscas la forma de hacer un array en sql?

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos estás utilizando? ¿MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server? Ponlo en las etiquetas de tu pregunta.

Comment: Agregado! Mysql

Comment: Mysql no soporta Arrays, buscando un ejemplo encontre esta otra pregunta que la respuesta te puede ayudar a "imitar" un array https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8381/crear-un-array-en-pl-sql-de-mysql?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la SP tú puedes definir una variable que sería tomada de forma aleatoria y luego usar esa variable en el `INSERT`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 2, 'Hernesto', 'Carlos') INTO @mRandom;
INSERT INTO Persona (Nombre ) VALUES (@mRandom);
```

Aquí, cada vez que se llame la SP, `@mRandom` tomará un valor aleatorio, el cual será insertado.

Para tomar el valor aleatorio se ha usado `ELT()`, combinado con `RAND()`, ([ver fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301988/5587982)) ten en cuenta que siempre debes multiplicar por el total de elementos que haya en la lista de valores. Dado que aquí son sólo dos valores, hemos puesto un `2`.